# Prove that $|P(X)| = 2^{|X|}$

Tags: sets

Prove that for any finite set $X$, $|P(X)| = 2^{|X|}$. The solution should use induction.

Comment: This is a problem statement, not a question. Please include your own effort and a specific question reagarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basis
    $$ |X| = 0 $$
    $$|P(X)| = 2^{|X|} = 2^0 = 1$$
    True. Any set with zero elements takes the form $\{\}$, and thus its power set will be $\{\{\}\}$. One element.

Inductive Step

We must show:
    $$|P(X+1)| = 2^{|X+1|}$$
    Thus:
    $$|P(X+1)| = 2^{|X+1|} = 2*2^{|X|} = 2*|P(X)|$$
    This is true because, if $X$ as a set grows by one, the power set, for every member in its set now has a new binary choice: include the new element or not. Thus the power set doubles.